# Why does program stop unexpectedly?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a very basic program that aims for the text view to display the phrase "Hello" after a button is pressed on the screen, but cannot figure out why every time I run it, it says that the application has stopped unexpectedly.

This is the program I wrote:

```
public class EtudeActivityActivity extends Activity{
  TextView tvResponse;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView tvResponse = (TextView)  findViewById (R.id.tvResponse);
  }


  public void updateTV(View v) {
    tvResponse.setText("Hello");
  }
}
```

Also, I inserted an `android:onClick = "updateTV"` into my main.xml file for the button.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you don't set the `tvResponse` member variable.  Instead you set a new local variable by the same name.  So when you call `setText()`, you are accessing an invalid reference

You need to change

```
final TextView tvResponse = (TextView)  findViewById (R.id.tvResponse);
```

to

```
tvResponse = (TextView)  findViewById (R.id.tvResponse);
```

to set the member variable, so it has a valid reference later on (when `updateTV()` is called)

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! Why exactly did it not work when I defined the tvresponse as a text view in finding its id?

Comment: Because the local definition of `tvResponse` hid the member variable, so you were not changing the member variable -- thus leaving it at its default value: `null`.  Once `onCreate()` finished, the result of `findViewById()` was lost.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've got an *instance* variable called `tvResponse` which you haven't shown us - that's what the `updateTV` method will refer to. That's entirely separate from the *local* `tvResponse` variable you've declared inside `onCreate`. I suspect that if you change the last line of `onCreate` from a local variable declaration to a simple assignment to the `tvResponse` variable, it may work. Otherwise, if nothing is assigning a value to the instance `tvResponse` variable, it will have the default value of `null`, causing a `NullPointerException` in `updateTV`.